# How do I retrieve values of a buttons which I am generating through a Iterator in Django?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, python-3.x, django-forms

```
<form action="." method="POST" role="form">
{% csrf_token %}
    <legend>Form title</legend>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">label</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Input field">
    </div>

    {% for item in items  %}
        <button type="button" name="abc" value="2" class="btn btn-default">{{item}}</button>
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here I am generating buttons through Iterator.I want to increment value of the button on button click and then submit the final value for all the generated buttons.
How do I retrieve the value for each button using Post?

Comment: you are storing this `button` value to db on POST ?

Comment: @sideffect0 Yes for every item I am going to make an entry with the final value in the database.

Comment: then pass the value from database to the view using context dict from view function or class

Comment: @sideffect0 I have done that.I am talking about retrieving those values after form submission.Basically I am creating a transaction form.The employee will click on the items(buttons) the user has bought.For every item purchased I want a seperate database entry.So I want to know what items and how many items the customer purchased.This  I want to retrieve in the post request.

Comment: All you need is a model ( Item model ?) linking it to User ( Foreignkey ?)
then on this view page, load the model data with filter by logined user, then pass the item data to view ( to context)

Comment: sideffect0 I have everything setup. All I want to know is which buttons the user clicked in the post request. The problem is that I have used a iterator to render the items. Now I want to retrieve value for every item seperately.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use input array in html form

```
{% for item in items  %}
 <button type="button" name="abc[{{ item.pk }}]" value="{{ item.value }}" class="btn btn-default">{{item}}  </button>
{% endfor %}
```

you can use [this](https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser) project for parsing array data.Note that you are in a situation of a dynamic form spend sometime on this post from the Jacobian ( co-creator of Django framework) [here](https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/) ( old though! ).

Comment: Ohk.Now how do i access it.
print(request.POST['abc[0]'] ?